# Python product of arbitrary number of variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, primes, prime-factoring

EDIT: Though I did say in the original post that I'd like to use list comprehension, I would gladly accept any solution. I simply assumed list comprehension would be the simplest way to do it.

---

I am working on a problem involving prime factorization, and have run into an issue regarding list comprehension.

I have a list of prime factors of a number, and of course the list could be any number of numbers. It could be [2,3,5] or just [2], or [2,3,11,17], etc.

What I would like to be able to do would be to find all products of powers of these numbers such that the product is less than or equal to 100,000. So for example if my prime factorization is [2,3,5], I would like to have all numbers of the form (2^a)(3^b)(5^c) for natural numbers a,b,c, satisfying (2^a)(3^b)(5^c) <= 100,000.

Is there a way to do this with list comprehension given that the number of prime factors is an arbitrary length?

Comment: You could probably jam it into one list comprehension, but it would probably be more readable to break it out into a function (possibly a generator).

Comment: I don't believe it is possible using list comprehension.  The parameters are far to broad to stuff into a single comprehension statement.

Comment: Can you define a function and use it in your list comprehension?

Comment: @not_a_robot I don't see why not. I'm new to Python though, so I'm not sure how that would help.

Comment: @James It doesn't need to use list comprehension. I just figured that that would be the best way to do it. If you have an alternative I would gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursive function that picks one of the factors and multiplies the current total until the total is above the limit. For each iteration you could then recursively call the same function while moving to next factor. Once you have exhausted all the factors just yield the current total:

```
def prods(factors, limit, index = 0, total = 1):
    # Base case, yield current number
    if index >= len(factors):
        yield total
        return

    while total <= limit:
        # Python 3 yield from could be used
        for res in prods(factors, limit, index + 1, total):
            yield res
        total *= factors[index]

print list(prods([2, 3, 5], 100))
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 25, 3, 15, 75, 9, 45, 27, 81, 2, 10, 50, 6, 30, 18, 90, 54, 4, 20, 100, 12, 60, 36, 8, 40, 24, 72, 16, 80, 48, 32, 96, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
import math

Nmax = 100
primeLst = [2, 3, 5]


result = []
enumMax = [int(math.floor(math.log(Nmax) / math.log(i))) for i in primeLst]

def prod(i, curRes):
    if curRes > Nmax:
        return
    if i==len(primeLst):
        result.append(curRes)
    else:
        for j in range(enumMax[i]+1):
            prod(i+1, curRes * (primeLst[i]**j))

prod(0, 1)

# result: [1, 5, 25, 3, 15, 75, 9, 45, 27, 81, 2, 10, 50, 6, 30, 18, 90, 54, 4, 20, 100, 12, 60, 36, 8, 40, 24, 72, 16, 80, 48, 32, 96, 64]
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `25` in the results since `2**0 * 3**0 * 5**2 = 25`?

Answer (score 0):

This modification of @niemmi's answer uses `heapq.merge` to merge each of the sequences from each of the recursive calls to produce the products in increasing order:

```
from heapq import merge

def prods(factors, limit, index = 0, total = 1):
    # Base case, yield current number
    if index >= len(factors):
        yield total
        return
    iters = []
    while total < limit:
        iters.append(prods(factors, limit, index + 1, total))
        total *= factors[index]
    for res in merge(*iters):
        yield res

print list(prods([2, 3, 5], 100))
```

There is the output:

```
>>> print list(prods([2, 3, 5], 100))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 54, 60, 64, 72, 75, 80, 81, 90, 96]
```